# programmatically sync time on non-domain machine with domain controller

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm looking for a way to sync time on non-domain xp machine with domain controller in Active Directory.
I know we can use net use then net time command, but I wonder if there is any other way of doing it, because I don't really like to invoke a process.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen nothing in the .Net framework that supports this. Your best bet is to execute `w32tm /resync`

Comment: He says "net" not ".net". There actually is a command named "net".

Comment: @TomTom: The question was tagged c# and the caller clearly stated a desire to not start a process, thus implying the request was looking for a solution within the .Net framework. NET TIME has been deprecated and NET TIME /SET requires a response, thus making w32tm /resync the best option.